# onCreateOptionsMenu() does not work in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement a search Filter in my Fragment, but it does not let me. I used the same code in Activity before and it worked. Whenever I type something, the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` does not get called. The App looks like this : [![app Picture][1]][1]
As you can see I type something in the top and it won't get filtered.

My Fragment code: `

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    setMenuVisibility(false);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
    if(getArguments() != null){
        String yourText = getArguments().getString("interessen");
        System.out.println(yourText);
    }`
```

.
.
.

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuevents, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    MenuItem searchitem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchEvent);
    //searchitem.setVisible(false);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchitem.getActionView();
    final List<Event> allEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    allEvents.addAll(eventList);

    searchitem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            eventList.clear();
            eventList.addAll(allEvents);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {

            eventList.clear();
            eventList.addAll(allEvents);
            return true;
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            eventListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }

    });
```

I did not copy the `EventListAdapter` in, becuase this should work just fine. Its just that the Fragment does not get Access to the SearchItem.

Anybody? :)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkLcL.png

Answer (score 0):

You've called `setMenuVisibility()`, which means your Fragment is specifically opting out of having its menu being shown. It is expected that when your menu isn't shown, `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is not triggered.

Remove that line of code to have your menu actually be visible.